# C# Execute resgen.exe with command prompt

Tags: c#, cmd, command, console-application, resgen

I'm creating a console application which I will use to control the Internationalization in different languages for C# applications.

The only problem I have is that I need to create a .resource file via cmd using the command **resgen InputFile OutputFile**. To execute this command, I have my own command in which I generate the specified files ( strings-ca-ES.txt, strings.ca-ES.xaml, ...) that the command needs to be executed. Post-creating these files, the program starts a System.Diagnostics.Process with FileName "cmd.exe" and the arguments "resgen strings.ca-ES.txt". After that, another Process is executed with the command "resgen strings.ca-ES.txt strings.ca-ES.resources". Neither the first nor the second are executed and when I write the same commands in the same prompt window ( it was not closed yet ) it gives me the next message:

```
"resgen" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable
```

It means that the command **resgen** was not found but I have the path to it in the environment variables.

Any help will be well recieved.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `"resgen.exe"`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. The problem is that the cmd doesn't recognize the command "resgen" but if I open another cmd window and I write resgen, it is recognized

Comment: I just found the solution. Restart windows.